# getting MDB_MAP_RESIZED error for 2k textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, runtime-error, textures

When I try to use 2k (2048x2048) textures in my Unity project I usually (but not always) get these 6 errors on play:

```
Assertion failed on expression: 'm_ErrorCode == MDB_MAP_RESIZED || !HasAbortingErrors()'
Artifact meta info not present for hash 41bf14bd946edde621130341baa11ff6
Asset database transaction committed twice!
Assertion failed on expression: 'errors == MDB_SUCCESS || errors == MDB_NOTFOUND'
```

Always works fine with 512x512 textures and usually works fine with 1024x1024 textures. I'm using the RGB565 texture format, and the textures are all jpegs.

When I get these errors, the meshes are just textured solid black. When I dont get these errors, my textures import correctly. Sometimes I see my textures render for the first frame, and then my meshes go black.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your images are corrupt and missing meta data:

```
Artifact meta info not present for hash 41bf14bd946edde621130341baa11ff6
```

If you can somehow open your images in an image editor (GIMP, Photoshop) and save them as new files that should fix your error. PNG is a pretty standard image type in video games.

Comment: Thank you! Trying this out now. Will update when I'm done and checkmark if it works.

Comment: Sounds good let me know if it works, there is also a unity forum post from four years ago that references a bug in the engine

Comment: opened them all in paint, saved them as pngs, reimported into unity, and enabled Read/Write, and swapped them in, but I'm still getting black meshes :( I'm NOT getting the errors anymore, however...

Comment: Could you post the forum thread? I couldn't find anything related to unity when I googled for it

Comment: were you able to get the images open and save them out as pngs? https://forum.unity.com/threads/assertion-failed-assertion-failed-on-expression-kvalidsceneobjectidentifier-res.498303/

Comment: Yeah, they open fine in paint. I saved them as PNGs, and replaced the old JPGs with the PNGs in unity. Every once in a while the textures will load in, but usually I get black meshes. Also, it seems to be either all or nothing. Either all the textures load in, or none of them do.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? Can I see a screenshot of your editor with the material attached to the object in view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213894/discussion-between-the8thbit-and-vasmos).